# Syntax Error in Racket equal?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I am trying pass in a list input to conversation and have the function check to see if the first element in another list (keyword) matches to the first element of the list that user passed in. If the two match then output a zero otherwise pass the tail of the inputted list recursively back to itself.

```
(define keyword '(am I))

(define (conversation input)
     (cond
      ((equal? (car keyword) (car input)) 0)
      (else (conversation (cdr input)))))
```

The error I get is:

```
car: contract violation
expected: pair?
given: '()
```

I understand that equal? compares two elements, a pair, but what I do not understand is why it would create an error when the car of both lists are both exactly an element. Any help would be much appreciated, I'm assuming the solution is rather simple but I can't seem to see it.

My goal is create several functions that pattern match and output appropriate dialog but without the use of regular expressions or other libraries. There is no mandate not to use the two mentioned above but I would like to do it without them to get a better understanding of the logic and the code. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You never handle when `input` is empty. You also don’t show what you’re actually calling `conversation` with, so it’s hard to know what exactly is producing the error.

Comment: There is no `car` of `'()`.

Comment: Sorry about that! I'm calling conversation with (conversation '(Hello World)) and I just added ((empty? input) 0) to the beginning of the cond.
@law-of-fives where would I need to add '() ? should it be at keyword and input?

Comment: That should fix the error, but now your function always returns 0.

Comment: Hey Brendan, checking if the input is empty did exactly as you said, but why would it always return 0? If it evaluates the input to not be 0, shouldn't it move on the the next condition?

Comment: @ArenTahmasian In the event you don't find the element you return `0`, the same as when you do find it. With the same answer for both base cases you really could have simplified it to `(define (conversation input) 0)`

Comment: @Sylwester, sorry I forgot to add that I replaced 0 with "Empty List"

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to consider is that you have no condition of failure. You assume there's either a match *now* with the `car`, or there will be a match later with the `cdr`. But there may be no match at all, and you will `cdr` down your list until your list is `'()`. As there is no such thing as the `car` of `'()` you are getting an error when you try to extract it. Therefore the first thing to do is make sure you've handled this case. I don't know what you intend to do in this case, so I have made the procedure return `#f`.

Next you consider what to do if the symbols do match. In your case you are choosing to return `0`. This part seems to have no problems.

Finally, we consider what to do if the `car`s do not match. In this case we continue searching the input. This part seems to have no problems.

```
(define (conversation input)
  (cond ((null? input) #f)
        ((eq? (car input) (car keyword))
         0)
        (else
         (conversation (cdr input)))))
```